# Run each Docker container in a specific user namespace configuration

Tags: linux, docker, file-permissions, linux-namespaces

**Problem:**

I am trying to mount a directory as Docker volume in such a way,
that a user, which is created inside a container could write
into a file in that volume. And at the same time, the file should
be at least readable to my user `lape` outside the container.

Essentially, I need to remap a user UID from container user namespace to a specific UID on the host user namespace.

How can I do that?

I would prefer answers that:

- do not involve changing the way how Docker daemon is run;
- and allows a possibility to configure container user namespace for each container separately;
- do not require rebuilding the image;
- I would accept answer that shows a nice solution using [Access Control Lists](https://linux.die.net/man/5/acl) as well;

**Setup:**

This is how the situation can be replicated.

I have my Linux user `lape`, assigned to `docker` group, so I
can run Docker containers without being root.

```
lape@localhost ~ $ id
uid=1000(lape) gid=1000(lape) groups=1000(lape),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),121(lpadmin),131(sambashare),999(docker)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --update su-exec && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# I create a user inside the image which i want to be mapped to my `lape`
RUN adduser -D -u 800 -g 801 insider
VOLUME /data

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
chmod 755 /data
chown insider:insider /data

# This will run as `insider`, and will touch a file to the shared volume
# (the name of the file will be current timestamp)
su-exec insider:insider sh -c 'touch /data/$(date +%s)'

# Show permissions of created files
ls -las /data
```

Once the is built with:

```
docker build -t nstest
```

I run the container:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/data:/data nstest
```

The output looks like:

```
total 8
 4 drwxr-xr-x    2 insider  insider       4096 Aug 26 08:44 .
 4 drwxr-xr-x   31 root     root          4096 Aug 26 08:44 ..
 0 -rw-r--r--    1 insider  insider          0 Aug 26 08:44 1503737079
```

So the file seems to be created as user `insider`.

From my host the permissions look like this:

```
lape@localhost ~ $ ls -las ./data
total 8
4 drwxr-xr-x 2  800  800 4096 Aug 26 09:44 .
4 drwxrwxr-x 3 lape lape 4096 Aug 26 09:43 ..
0 -rw-r--r-- 1  800  800    0 Aug 26 09:44 1503737079
```

Which indicates that the file belongs to uid=800 (that is the `insider` user which does not even exist outside the Docker namespace).

**Things I tried already:**

1. I tried specifying `--user` parameter to `docker run`, but it seems it can only map which user on the host is mapped to uid=0 (root) inside the docker namespace, in my case the `insider` is not root. So it did not really work in this case.
2. The only way how I achieved `insider`(uid=800) from within container, to be seen as lape(uid=1000) from host, was by adding `--userns-remap="default"` to the `dockerd` startup script, and adding `dockremap:200:100000` to files `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` as suggested in [documentation for --userns-remap](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/). Coincidentally this worked for me, but it is not sufficient solution, because:

   - it requires reconfigure the way how the Docker daemon runs;
   - requires to do some arithmetic on user ids: '200 = 1000 - 800', where 1000 is the UID my user on the host, and 800 the UID is of the `insider` user;
   - that would not even work if the insider user would need to have a higher UID than my host user;
   - it can only configure how user namespaces are mapped globally, without a way to have unique configuration per container;
   - this solution kind of works but it is a bit too ugly for practical usage.

Comment: Did you take a look at user namespaces in docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/ ?

Comment: Yes, checked that as well. I actually wrote some conclusions on that at the end of my original post. I have a feeling that 'userns-remap' is more a feature that prevents UID clashes in the host and container namespaces, however, what I want is an overlap of a user in the host and in the containers. Another thing is that 'userns-remap' is created when docker daemon starts, and there is no way to configure it for individual containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a read access for your user, the simplest will be to add the read permissions for all files and subdirectories in `/data` with acls outside of docker.

Add default acl: `setfacl -d -m u:lape:-rx /data`.

You will also need to give access to the directory itself: `setfacl -m u:lape:-rx /data`.

Are there any obstacles for such a solution?